# Invoke DisposableBean destroy() method in SpringBoot app running on OpenShift when pod is shut down

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, spring-boot-actuator

I have a SpringBoot running on OpenShift and I have a destroy() method in a class that implements DisposableBean. When I hit the /actuator/shutdown endpoint locally to kill the app my destroy() method is invoked as expected. However when I deploy the app to our OpenShift test environment, then kill the pod, my destroy() method doesn't appear to be invoked at all.

Is there a change I can make to my app to ensure this method gets invoked when pods are terminated, or is there some config in OpenShift that I could request our admins make to have my method invoked on shutdown?

Comment: you could try to add the following config to your application.yml

`server:
  shutdown: graceful
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 60s`